# Xtext DSL editor referring to the Java classes defined in my model

Tags: dsl, pojo, xtext

I have set of java classes and I want to refer them in the DSL which I am trying to edit using Xtext grammar. e.g. There is a class Employee :

```
class Employee{
  String name;
  double salary;
  String organisation;
  String status;
}
```

Now in my DSL I wish to use them. Hence when user is trying the name he should get  these tree attributes as help. e.g. DSL i will like to trite like this:

```
employee.salary > 100000 then employee.status='GOLD'
```

My question is when i am typing the name such as employee than all the three attributes should be available to user as context help.

Comment: the thing to look at is called scoping. your snippet and information tell to few things to give an detailed answer

Comment: also the question would be if you already use xbase (then this should work ootb)

Comment: "the thing to look at is called scoping." i am not clear about this, please help.

Comment: again your dont tell enhough. do you use xbase. how does your grammar look like etc